# How to inject services into AuditingStore?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, aspnetboilerplate

I have replaced the `AuditingStore` with my own so that I can set the `CustomData` field, and this is working great.

```
public class MyAuditingStore : AuditingStore
{
    public MyAuditingStore(IRepository<AuditLog, long> auditLogRepository)
        : base(auditLogRepository)
    {
    }

    public override Task SaveAsync(AuditInfo auditInfo)
    {
        auditInfo.CustomData = "certain additional data that is not captured by default";
        return base.SaveAsync(auditInfo);
    }
}
```

But now I want to know how to inject services into the `AuditingStore` so that I can retrieve other information during `SaveAsync`. How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to how you would inject services elsewhere.

```cs
public class MyAuditingStore : AuditingStore
{
    private readonly OtherInformationService _otherInformationService;

    public MyAuditingStore(
        IRepository<AuditLog, long> auditLogRepository,
        OtherInformationService otherInformationService)
        : base(auditLogRepository)
    {
        _otherInformationService = otherInformationService;
    }

    public override Task SaveAsync(AuditInfo auditInfo)
    {
        auditInfo.CustomData = otherInformationService.GetOtherInformation();
        return base.SaveAsync(auditInfo);
    }
}

public class OtherInformationService : ITransientDependency
{
    public string GetOtherInformation()
    {
        return "other information";
    }
}
```